# XENFORO: CAPTCHA on create/reply a thread

Tags: captcha, xenforo

Is there any way to enable the CAPTCHA for new thread and for reply a thread or we have to use a custom addon for that

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is custom addon for this which we can use
https://brivium.com/resources/captcha-on-posting.17